# Ajax using JQuery success function is not called

Tags: jquery, servlets

**1. servlet file**

```
public class StudentController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("inside servlet");

     dao dao=new daoimpl();
    String action=(request.getParameter("action"));
    if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("login")){
        System.out.println("inside login");
        Student student=new Student();
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("username"));


        student.setUsername(request.getParameter("username"));
        student.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));
        ArrayList<Student>al=dao.getAllStudent(student);
        Gson gson=new Gson();
        //PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
            String json = gson.toJson(al);
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write(json);
    }
```

```html
index.jsp
<html>
<head>
   <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#login').click(function(event) {
     var uname = $('#username').val();
        var pass = $('#pass').val();
        alert(uname+"-----"+pass);
        
     alert("on click");
        $.post("Controller?action=login",{
                username : uname,
                password : pass
             },function(data) {
              alert("sucess");    
             var json=$.parseJSON(data);
                  alert(json);
});
        });
});
  </script>
    
</head>
<body>
<form action="login" method="post">
User Name:<input type="text" name="uname" id="username"><br>
Password:<input type="text" name="password" id="pass"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login" id="login">
<a href="registration.jsp">Register</a>
<h3 align="center">student Details</h3>
<div id="tablediv">
<table cellspacing="0" id="studenttable">
</table>
</div></form></body>
</html>
```

not even sucess alert working in the code,please suggest me i m new for jquery thanks in advance..

Comment: your login button is of type `submit` your form is probably going to submit before your ajax finishes processing.

Comment: thank you so much sir...but data is getting null on alert(json); at this line while arraylist properly getting on servlet.so what i do can you please tell me?

Comment: add `alert(data);` before `alert(json);`. What does it output?

Comment: Thanks sir..now it is working.got it no need to parse data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
  function() {
      $('form').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

         var uname = $('#username').val();
            var pass = $('#pass').val();
            alert(uname+"-----"+pass);            
            alert("on submit");


            $.ajax(
              {
                url:"Controller?action=login",
                data: {username : uname,password : pass}
                type:'post',
                cache:false,
                timeout:8000
              }
            ).done(function(data){
                alert("sucess");    
                var json=$.parseJSON(data);
                alert(json);

            }).fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error){
              alert(textStatus);
              alert(error);
            });
      });
    }
  );
</script>
```